# PostgreSQL doesn't contain some required header files

Tags: postgresql, pycparser

I have installed pycparser that parses C code.

Using pycparser I want to parse an open source project, namely PostgreSQL . However, during compilation it cannot found some header files, namely 
`pg_config_ext.h` and `pg_config_os.h`.

While looking at the directory structure of PostgreSQL, I find that it does not have these header files. How to fix this issue?

Comment: I think they're generated when you run [`configure`](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/configure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These header files are generated from the respective `.in` files when `configure` is run.

This will allow conditional compilation depending on the operating system and its configuration.

To compile PostgreSQL, you need what is called a *configured source tree* in PostgreSQL jargon.

Also note that the build process is somewhat different on Windows, see [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/install-windows.html) for details.

Comment: It's worth noting that these auto-generated files are typically specific to the local distribution and compiler environment and may vary considerably from one machine to another.

Comment: The Previous errors are resolved. Thanx for the help. But new errors have arised as while parsing "complex.c" file of postgresql. It cannot find "winsock2.h","windows.h" files. Is this related to platform i am using (using 64-bit windows 10 and postgresql-11.0).